# Hangman game performance

Tags: python, performance, hangman

I want to change (for better performance) or optimize my code, especially `for` and `while` loops, maybe with lambdas or list comprehensions.

```
def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    '''
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters that represents what letters have not
      yet been guessed.
    '''
    alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    alphabet2 = alphabet[:]

    def removeDupsBetter(L1, L2):
        L1Start = L1[:]
        for e in L1:
            if e in L1Start:
                L2.remove(e)
        return ''.join(str(e) for e in L2)

    return removeDupsBetter(lettersGuessed, alphabet2)


def hangman(secretWord):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the secret word to guess.

    Starts up an interactive game of Hangman.

    * At the start of the game, let the user know how many 
      letters the secretWord contains.

    * Ask the user to supply one guess (i.e. letter) per round.

    * The user should receive feedback immediately after each guess 
      about whether their guess appears in the computers word.

    * After each round, you should also display to the user the 
      partially guessed word so far, as well as letters that the 
      user has not yet guessed.

    Follows the other limitations detailed in the problem write-up.
    '''
    intro = str(len(secretWord))
    lettersGuessed = []
    guess = str
    mistakesMade = 8
    wordGuessed = False

    print 'Welcome to the game, Hangman!'
    print ('I am thinking of a word that is ') + intro + (' letters long.')
    print ('------------')

    while mistakesMade > 0 and mistakesMade <= 8 and wordGuessed is False:
        if secretWord == getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
            wordGuessed = True
            break
        print ('You have ') + str(mistakesMade) + (' guesses left.')
        print ('Available letters: ') + getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed)
        guess = raw_input('Please guess a letter: ').lower()
        if guess in secretWord:
            if guess in lettersGuessed:
                print ("Oops! You've already guessed that letter: ") + getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed)
                print ('------------')
            else:
                lettersGuessed.append(guess)
                print ('Good guess: ') + getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed)
                print ('------------')
        else:
            if guess in lettersGuessed:
                print ("Oops! You've already guessed that letter: ") + getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed)
                print ('------------')
            else:
                lettersGuessed.append(guess)
                mistakesMade -= 1
                print ('Oops! That letter is not in my word: ') + getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed)
                print ('------------')

    if wordGuessed == True:
        return 'Congratulations, you won!'
    elif mistakesMade == 0:
        print ('Sorry, you ran out of guesses. The word was ') + secretWord
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the definition of the function `getGuessedWord`.

Comment: Note that the following are equivalent: `alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
;
alphabet_easier = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
`

Comment: Note that the different printing stanzas are quite similar: you may want to create a function for printing, and call it with the appropriate arguments.

Comment: Your `mistakesMade` variable is actually not counting mistakes, but guesses: you may want to rename it.

Answer (score 5):

For the first function you could use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) operations and the built-in [`string`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) module:

```
import string

ALPHABET = set(string.ascii_lowercase)

def get_available_letters(letters_guessed):
    '''
    letters_guessed: iterable, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters that represents what letters have not
      yet been guessed.
    '''
    return "".join(sorted(ALPHABET - set(letters_guessed)))
```

Note that I renamed your function/variables to adhere to Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

If you don't care that the return value is sorted, or a string, you can just return the set right away:

```
def get_available_letters(letters_guessed):
    '''
    letters_guessed: iterable, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: set, letters that have not yet been guessed.
    '''
    return ALPHABET - set(letters_guessed)
```

In your actual game function, here are a few nitpicks:

- Use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for an easier way to put some value somewhere in a text. This changes `print ('I am thinking of a word that is ') + intro + (' letters
  long.')` to `print 'I am thinking of a word that is {} letters
  long.'.format(len(secretWord))` and `print ('You have ') + str(mistakesMade) + (' guesses left.')` to `print ('You have {} guesses left.'.format(mistakesMade))`
- `while mistakesMade > 0 and mistakesMade <= 8 and wordGuessed is False:` could be `while 0 < mistakesMade <= 8 and not wordGuessed`
- Use a `set` also for `lettersGuessed`, then `if guess in lettersGuessed:` becomes \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$, instead of \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$
- `if wordGuessed == True:` can just be `if wordGuessed:`

Answer (score 5):

Since [Graipher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/98493/graipher) already did excellent job discussing [`get_available_letters()`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/160933/127098) and more general structuring, I will look at the main loop.  General discussion first, and then some restructured code below.

**Name variables how they are used:**

Your code uses a variable named `mistakesMade`, but its primary purpose is as `guesses_left`.  So I renamed it.

**Try not to test the same thing twice:**

If you do not need to test a condition twice, then it is better not to.  In the case of this code, I removed a couple of tests that were after the main loop.  I did this by performing the action in the loop after the test, and then just breaking out of the loop.  Some advantages in this case include that all of the logic in the while statement as well as the tracking variable were no longer needed.

**Remove redundant code:**

Anytime you find yourself writing the exact same code more than once, you should look for a restructure opportunity to remove the duplicate code.  It is not always worth removing the first duplicate, but it often is.  And by the time you get to three copies of the same code it is almost always good to restructure to get rid of the copies.

In this case `prints` that were exactly the same were a good clue that things could be simplified.

**Loop Code:**

```
while True:
    print('You have %d guesses left.' % guesses_left)
    print('Available letters: ' + getAvailableLetters(letters_guesses))
    guess = raw_input('Please guess a letter: ').lower()

    if guess in letters_guesses:
        msg = "Oops! You've already guessed that letter: "

    else:
        letters_guesses.append(guess)

        if secretWord == getGuessedWord(secretWord, letters_guesses):
            print('Congratulations, you won!')
            break

        if guess in secretWord:
            msg = 'Good guess: '
        else:
            guesses_left -= 1
            if guesses_left == 0:
                print('Sorry, you ran out of guesses. The word was '
                      + secretWord)
                break
            msg = 'Oops! That letter is not in my word: '

    print(msg + getGuessedWord(secretWord, letters_guesses))
    print('------------')
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the maintenance of the list of letters is insignificant compared to the cost of the rest of the code – mostly the chatter with the player.

Here is what I could consider doing.  Have an `int` with 26 bits, then use arithmetic to convert a `char` into a bit position.
Given that `alpha` is the integer containing the current state of the letters, and `letter` contains the letter in question.

**Note**: I don't know the exact syntax in Python, but something like this:

```
alpha |=   (1 << (letter - ord('a')));    # turns on a bit
alpha &=  ~(1 << (letter - ord('a')));    # turns off a bit
if alpha & (1 << (letter - ord('a')))...  # tests if the letter has been used
```

Caveat 1:  This solution is limited to a small, compact set of letters, such as exhibited in lowercase English letters.  (Most character sets encode English letters in a way compatible with this "bit" technique.)

Caveat 2:  Since the Question asked only about performance, I present this technique as a way to improve performance, not necessarily readability, language expansion, etc.

Comment: FWIW whilst bit arithmetic is possible in Python code is normally far nicer if you use something else. For example Graipher's code is very readable and everything is contained in one line.

Comment: Actually, encoding as a specific number of bits fossilises the code, making it too inflexible to work with languages with more (Swedish) or fewer (Irish) letters than English.  So probably weak from a maintainability point of view.

Comment: @TobySpeight - I added Caveats.